# AVAssetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler Cannot call method when status is 0

Tags: avassetwriter, xcode10, ios12

I am struggling with issue in new iOS 12 and Xcode 10. When I start screen recording it crashes and show me following log

```
2018-09-22 08:00:09.459676+0530 Chat story[95207:3292867] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '*** -[AVAssetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:] Cannot call method when status is 0'
```

In last version of Xcode it was working fine.

Also here is my code which I wrote for this

```
func startRecording(withFileName fileName: String, recordingHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void,onCompletion: @escaping (Error?)->Void)
    {
        self.viewOverlay.show()

        screenRecorder.startRecording(withFileName: fileName) { (error) in
            recordingHandler(error)
            self.recordCompleted = onCompletion
        }
    }

    func stopRecording()
    {
        screenRecorder.stopRecording { (error) in
            self.viewOverlay.hide()
            self.recordCompleted?(error)
        }
    }
```

Also on ScreenRecorder.swift there is another method which calls stopRecording Method. Here is that method

```
func stopRecording(handler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
        {
            if #available(iOS 11.0, *)
            {
                RPScreenRecorder.shared().stopCapture
                {    (error) in
                        handler(error)
                        self.assetWriter.finishWriting
                    {
                        print(ReplayFileUtil.fetchAllReplays())

                    }
                }
            } else {
                // Fallback on earlier versions
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show your code, @CodeHunter.

Comment: @matt I updated question. Please have a look

Comment: And what line are you crashing on?

Comment: @matt its crashing on self.assetWriter.finishWriting